# Responsive Image in section id

Tags: responsive

All i want for the picture is to showcase exactly the same when i use the page on a phone. I dont want it to be full size or whatever, I want it to look the same but become smaller. SO here's what i got to work with:

```css
#showcase{
  min-height:400px;
  background:url('../img/showcase.jpg') no-repeat 0 -400px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#ffffff;
  
}
```

```html
<section id="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Digibox</h1>
        <p>Ditt digitala verktyg som tar hand om dina överföringar.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
```